# Series estimate

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\theta\in(0,1)$ be given.
I define for $a>0$ and $\lambda \ge 1$,
$
S(\lambda,a )=\sum_{k\ge 1} k^{\frac12-\theta}e^{-a\vert k-\lambda\vert}.
$
I want to prove that
$$
\sup_{\substack{a\in(0,1)\\\lambda \ge 1}}S(\lambda,a)\lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}+\theta} a^{1-\theta}=C(\theta)<+\infty.
$$
It looks like a rather trivial question, but I was only able to prove  a somewhat weaker estimate.

Answer (score 2):

I think the desired inequality is false. Suppose $\theta<\frac 12$; fix $a$ and set $\lambda=2N$ for a large integer $N$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\lambda^{-1/2+\theta}S(\lambda,a)&\ge \lambda^{-1/2+\theta}\sum_{k\le\lambda} k^{1/2-\theta}e^{-a|k-\lambda|}\\
&\ge (2N)^{-1/2+\theta}\sum_{N\le k\le 2N}k^{1/2-\theta}e^{-a(2N-k)}\\
&\ge 2^{-1/2}\sum_{N\le k\le 2N}e^{-a(2N-k)}\\
&\ge 2^{-1/2}\sum_{k\le N}e^{-a(N-k)}\\
&=2^{-1/2}\sum_{k\le N}e^{-ak}\\
&\sim \frac{1}{a\sqrt 2},
\end{align*}

Multiplying by $a^{1-\theta}$, you see the lower bound explodes as $\theta\to 0^+$.